# Multiple table linq query?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

Could you help me translate this SQL query in Linq and Lambda expression.

```
SELECT * FROM User
  JOIN UserIdentifier ON User.id = UserIdentifier.user_fk
  JOIN UserPassword ON User.id = UserPassword.user_fk
  WHERE UserIdentifier.identifier_value = "key" AND UserPassword.password = "1234"
```

I already wrote this

```
var query = from u in context.Users
            join ui in context.UserIdentifiers on u.id equals ui.user_fk into Joined
            from j in Joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join up in context.UserPasswords on u.id equals up.user_fk into Joined2
            from ???
            select new { id = u.id, identifier = j.identifier_value, password = Joined2.???}
```

with help of http://paragy.wordpress.com/2010/11/18/multiple-joins-with-linq-and-lambda/

I'm not a happy user of linq. Actually I don't like linq because of this kind of request. This one is simple but when you try complex request linq is a nightmare. It's even worst with dynamic request. I always have problem with linq syntax and the web doesn't really help. I don't find a correct documentation to write queries.

I guess I'm not the first one to ask this question but all the documentation I found seems wrong or doesn't help me. This is a simple query and I don't find correct help. I'm still waiting someone prove me that link is not just another POC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a `where` clause.

And your SQL joins are regular `INNER JOIN`s, so you don't need these `join ... into g from x in g.DefaultIfEmpty()` -> that's how you do an equivalent of `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

```
var query = from u in context.Users
            join ui in context.UserIdentifiers on u.id equals ui.user_fk
            join up in context.UserPasswords on u.id equals up.user_fk
            where ui.identifier_value == "key" && up.password == "1234"
            select new
            {
                id = u.id,
                identifier = ui.identifier_value,
                password = up.password
            };
```

Comment: You don't need the `into` clause to get desired SQL equivalent.